# Testing Paypal IPN

Tags: paypal-ipn

developer documentation seems to get worse over time and I can't locate the endpoints required any more:

I'm trying to send to my sandbox using:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

but constantly getting errors - is this the correct URL? Can anyone point me at the relevant sections of the sprawling docs?

thank!

Answer (score 0):

Directly below are a couple doc links:

[IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

[Cart Upload](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/?mark=cart%20upload)

Also, check the menu on the left when looking at those pages.  It is challenging to know what one's integration method is called let alone find documentation.  These URLs below are for uploading a shopping cart and for IPN.

Sandbox:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Live:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Comment: Yeah...what's the "uploading a shopping cart (via form post)" integration called anyway?